# How to lose 10 kg for a 15 year old girl

Tags: weight-loss, exercise

My height is 165 cm, and i just want to loose my thigh fat,calf fat and my muffin top

Comment: Eat less, exercise more.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried anything yet? Is something not working? For the purposes of my answer, I will assume you are inactive.

## TL;DR

- You aren't able to lose fat from certain areas of your body. Any exercise will help you lose fat including walking and running. If you wish to lose fat from the legs and tummy, focus more on toning those areas with lunges or squats
- Make sure you have measurable goals. You will find it hard to determine *when* you've lost your tummy fat, so ensure you are measuring either by taking measurements with a tape measure or a body composition test. Try to avoid weighing yourself

## Exercise

Losing fat from certain areas isn't possible (in fact: it's [disproven](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23222084)). If you are interested in *fixing* those areas, the way to do it would be to tone them up with muscle instead! It's likely the abdominal exercises and leg exercises would be the way to achieve this, and you can try **squats** and **lunges** as a way of engaging your legs and abs. Both are able to be performed without any equipment (you can just use your body weight) and both should leave you exhausted afterwards! As an example program, you could do what was taught to me as *24-7*: 24 squats, 24 lunges (12 each leg) and then a 100m sprint. Repeat for 7 times total. Try that 3 times a week (should take approx 20-30 minutes but don't fret if it takes you longer).

However, since those exercises won't help you lose fat in those areas any more than say bench pressing, you can simply do any exercise (walking, running, swimming, bench pressing etc). I recommend those exercises as a way of toning the muscle in those areas as well as losing fat (from your entire body).

Don't be afraid of the term *muscle* either: you don't have to worry about having enormous, muscly legs after a dozen squats. Body-builders spend years getting their bodies to look the way they are.

## Measurable goals

My final thing to mention is to have a measurable goal. Wanting to "lose fat from my thighs and tummy" is great for motivating yourself to do something, but you need to have a measurable goal and I recommend measuring yourself! Although you mention losing 10kg, depending on what you weigh that might be more difficult than you think. Start by taking measurements now and then repeat every 2-4 weeks (note: do not do it too frequently. Losing weight won't happen overnight!). Make sure you measure yourself consistently!

To measure your legs: take a tape measure mark the middle part of your leg from your hip to your knee. Then wrap the tape measure around and record the number.
To measure your tummy: wrap the tape measure around the largest part of your waist (where your belly button is)

I don't advise weighing yourself, since muscle weighs more than fat and if you start to build muscle (again: don't be scared of building muscle. Think of it more as sculpting your body) you won't necessarily lose weight. Taking measurements is far better for what you want, since even if you tone up with muscle your measurements will go down from the fat loss.

Alternatively, you can obtain a body composition test which will measure your fat and muscle percent.

## Diet

Note that when I use the word diet I am talking about the food you habitually eat. This only requires a brief mention, because as long as you aren't putting on weight the food you are eating is probably fine. Your body will convert your fat and carbs into energy for you when you start needing it (e.g. exercise), so it's more about *using* that energy than altering what you are eating. So: if your diet (the food you habitually eat) isn't causing you to gain weight, there's **no need to alter it**.

Comment: I really want to upvote this, but I feel like this is too much of a textbook answer. For someone of such a young age, it's too easy to get sucked up into the wrong mindset with dieting. It's becoming more [prevalent](https://www.nationaleatingdisorders.org/get-facts-eating-disorders) for younger girls to feel the need to diet. While I agree with what you've said here, I feel recommending a shift in focus to some sort of athletic or performance activity would be a healthier (psychologically) option rather than focusing on dieting.

Comment: @AlexL I agree with you that dieting isn't the right way, but I feel "Dieting" isn't mentioned in the answer at all. I mention diet (the noun) because exercise won't help if one is consuming more than their recommended intake. I don't mean one should eat less, but one should ensure they aren't eating too much. I wanted the key-part of the answer to be: "Exercise, and have measurable results"

Answer (score 0):

The [answer given above](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/27659/18169) is perfect. Just count calories and try to do more physical activities. Less calories in than out is the way to lose fat. A good app to track this is [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com): it's available on the internet, Android, iOS and Windows phone. I lost about 15kg using this.

Furthermore: if you are willing to lose weight, make sure to not overdo it. If you do you may binge and you'll get more calories in than out. Also if you overdo it you may overeat after you've completed your diet.